# is there any way to stream binary content with javascript

Tags: javascript, subsonic, html, google-chrome, audio-streaming

I am hoping to make an example using the developer build of chrome and being able to use subsonic to stream a binary audio file. So far I have not had any luck though.

Granted my next option will be try to load in the audio files into windowStorage and toss some magic dust on them.

Does anybody know a way to stream a audio file to the audio tag through binary?